# How to change the maximum memory a process can allocate (getting access violation everytime around 2040 MBs)

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, window, limit

I am running a process on a Windows 7 X64 with 6GB RAM. The problem rises when I want to commit more than near 2GB for this process. I wanted to use SetProcessWorkingSetSize() but it has no effects. Still getting access violation in about 2040 MB and more than 30% of the RAM is free. Also the oddest is the fact that the amount of allocated memory is the same in every run. My question is how can I use more than this value for my process? I need to take the most out of the RAM for this process. To test it, I wrote a simple code. As you can see I am not trying to allocate a big array, in each iteration of a while(1) loop I allocate only 640 bytes and access violation occurs exactly around 2040MBs.

Here is the code segment:

```
class Dummy
{
    long double x;
    long double y;
    long double z;
    long double k;
    long double l;
    long double m;
    long double n;
    long double p;
};
int main()
{
    while(1){new Dummy[10];}
}
```

Here is a screenshot of task manager:

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: If you need 2 gigs of RAM, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3: I am having applications that use 90+ GiB of RAM, they must be very wrong then I guess.

Comment: Using 2GB of RAM is perfectly meaningful at times. It may be wrong if you are running on a mobile phone, but in my 16GB machine, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes it is. However, it was also a question of curiosity. I have seen posts having similar problems but no real answer. The answer presented below is totally correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is compiled in 32 bits mode. As such, it can only use so much memory. This is an architecture limitation.

If you want it to be able to use more memory, you must compile it in 64 bits mode.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can set option /LARGEADDRESSAWARE to linker, then your programm will be available about 3GB RAM and still can be run on 32-bit systems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Actually, you get pretty close to 4GB on a 64-bit machine, because there is no kernel space taking up 1GB, as there is in a 32-bit OS. The Kernel is well hidden away in the top part of 64-bit address space, out of reach for the 32-bit applications [aside from a tiny little bit needed to "get to the kernel"].

Comment: Is that the reason why system-wide maximum is 512 pages smaller than the number of pages. This link: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspxis" said so.